# AlertDialog setContentView taking over screen

Tags: android, view, android-alertdialog

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm having a hard time setting a custom view for the body of an AlertDialog. Here's what I'm doing to set the custom view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_body, null));
}
```

Instead of setting the content of the body of the AlertDialog, the view is placed over the entire screen. How do I get the view just to replace the AlertDialog message body?

Comment: whose onCreate function is that, your activities?

Comment: The class that extends AlertDialog. But I got it working with AlertDialog.Builder.

Comment: I'd love to have a solution for the onCreate of an AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the activity's view by calling `setContentView` which is why it takes up the entire screen. You are also doing it in the `onCreate` method of what I assume is the activity, you need to do it in the `onCreateDialog` method.

Heres a link to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) and an example.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

            Dialog dialog = null;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(app);
            AlertDialog alert = null;

            builder.setTitle("A title") 
                   .setCancelable(true)
                   .setView(myView);
                alert = builder.create();
                return alert;

}
```

Comment: It's actually in the onCreate of the dialog, but I'll give that a shot. Thanks!